# How to support custom fields for an entity and list them as columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am currently working on a system which supports "custom fields" for users.

I will illustrate this with a simplified example of this database schema:

```
users
--------
user_id
name
age

custom_fields
----------------
custom_field_id 
custom_field_name

user_has_custom_field_value
------------------------
user_id (FK to users table)
custom_field_id (FK to custom_fields table)
custom_field_value (column that contains value of custom field)
```

This schema supports creation of custom fields to store information as per what the customer wishes.

However, I want to list all users along with their custom fields in the query output (or by using some PHP logic)

```
|  user_id    |    name     |    age    |    fav_sport    |    payment_mode   |    bank 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     3              John         28          Football           SWIFT             Chase
     6              Jane         24          Swimming           Cash               BOA
```

**fav_sport, payment_mode and bank are custom fields created which are represented as 3 rows in the custom_fields table.**

So, the custom_fields table looks like this :

```
custom_field_id     |      custom_field_name 
-----------------------------------------------
       1                     fav_sport
       2                     payment_mode
       3                     bank
```

and the user_has_custom_field value looks like this :

```
user_id    |        custom_field_id     |       custom_field_value     
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1                       1                          Football
   1                       2                           SWIFT
   1                       3                           Chase
   2                       1                          Swimming
   2                       2                           Cash
   2                       3                           BOA
```

What is the best way to achieve this with minimum queries and without taxing the database ?

The only solution I can come up with is by using a query inside a for loop in PHP to fetch the custom fields (which will definitely be heavy). What are more efficient solutions to do this ?

Suggestions welcome for MySQL based, PHP based, Stored Procedures etc.

Comment: use `JOIN`s for fetching data

Comment: You should look into `PIVOT`, which will allow you to turn those rows in the `custom_fields` table into headers in your results.

Comment: http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html contains useful examples on how to create PIVOT tables in MYSQL.